# Build Android OBOE using Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-audiomanager, ndk-build, oboe

I have gone through the documentation of the Android `C++` high performance audio library: [OBOE](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/GettingStarted.md). There is no documentation on how to add the library to an Android project that uses an `Android.mk` build type.

I am looking for ideas on how to implement this.

Comment: Use ndk to build the library

Comment: How will I do that? @SabaJafarzadeh

Comment: read the ndk document, basically you need to download ndk and use ndk-build on the root folder of Android.mk

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible to use the prefab version with ndk-build, but it's not difficult to build OBOE from source. First, clone the oboe repository. Then translate the `CMakeLists.txt` file included with OBOE to `Android.mk`. The result would look something like this:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := OBOE
OBOE_PATH := <path to oboe>
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(OBOE_PATH)/src/aaudio/AAudioLoader.cpp <all oboe sources...>
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(OBOE_PATH)/src $(OBOE_PATH)/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(OBOE_PATH)/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++17 -Ofast
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lOpenSLES
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then reference OBOE from your main module:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := OBOE
```

Comment: Why isn't it possible to use the prefab version with ndk-build?